# create multiple activities based on already created activity & java

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, copy

I am reasonably new to android studio, xml and java

thanks to this site and all its help i have managed to create a mainactivity

my mainactivity will create around 100 buttons, each leading to a new activity

i have created the 2nd activity and got it working as i want it

MY Question : 
How can i copy my second activity 100 times without having to manually create them all?

i can then edit each activity displayed image/text/sound etc

as my 2nd activity contains audio i would need to create the Java and XML

Also I am designing the app to work with multiple screen sizes so will need to copy the small/large/xlarge xml also

The only way i could see to create all this would be very tedious and would therefore appreciate any help with reducing the workload

Thanks in Advance

My 2nd activity code (XML & Java):

```
<TextView
    android:text="my text"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="blah blah blah"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="blah blah blah"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txt2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="blah blah blah"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txt3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

<Button
    android:text="click me"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/butt1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt3"
    android:background="@drawable/myimage"/>
```

JAVA

```
        @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    Button two = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.butt1);
    final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mymp3file);
    two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp1.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Obviously you should not mix data with UI elements ... If all your activities acts the same but with different data then obviosuly it should be one activity ... So i think that 2 activities is all what you need

Comment: thanks i have split the elements in the post now :)

Answer (score 0):

If all your activities are the same, I'd just use a single activity, and put your code in the onClick of the buttons.  You can change the UI and toolbar if you need to in there.

Comment: that sounds perfect, essentially all the activities will be the same just with different data however i am not sure what you mean by adding the code into the onclick

Comment: Each of the buttons will have an onclick method that they will extend. For each button say my button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener( hit return and it'll fill out your methods. Whatever you put in the onclick will get called when you tap it.

Comment: I just realized you have 100 buttons.  You're going to want to make a custom button for that.  Just so that there is a singular onClick.  If you're just learning how to do Android, you can list out the buttons, but that is bad form.  If it were me, I'd have a custom button, put the customized attributes I need in the xml to be read in to each button.  That way I'm only defining the buttons once in the xml, and the code will be relatively clean.

Comment: thanks for the advice, i think i get what your saying....rather than create 100 buttons with onclick, create a custom button that has onclick built in?  however the plan is the buttons (100) will display an image and text, then onclick move to a page displaying the same image, and some different text.....essentially a picture list of food leading to the same image and a description of how to cook etc (this is not my project but similar)....i have got the app working with 6 displayed buttons, and 6 separate xml pages, all displayed as i want...however i figure this is bad practice, TIA